# Is there a way to dynamically create objects based on a text file?

Tags: c++, parsing, dynamic, dynamically-generated, object-oriented-analysis

In building a simulator application and I would like to be able to save/load the simulation I am currently working on into a text file. I have a standard for the text file that is effectively a csv where each line corresponds to a component of the simulation and the first entry of each line is a string that uniquely identifies a given component. I would like to be able to parse this text file and, depending on that first entry, create an object of the corresponding component type dynamically.

The components are all defined in their own classes, which extend from a `Base` class. the result of this parsing should give me a list of `Base` pointers that are polymorphic pointers to the various components parsed from the text file. The most obvious solution to this problem is to have a giant if-else on the parsed type of the component:

```cpp
Base* p;
if(type == "A"){
    p = new A();
} else if(type == "B"){
    p = new B();
} ...
```

This is very tedious, though. So my next solution was to have a map, such that the key of an entry is the unique identifier string and the value is a function pointer to a function that returns a polymorphic pointer to a new instance of the corresponding component. That way I can just parse out the `type` string from the text file and run a line like this:

```cpp
Base* p = functionMap.at(type)();
```

Where each function in the map has a definition that looks like:

```cpp
//Note that this doesn't need to be scoped off of each class, I've only 
//done this to make it clear that this function could be an overridden 
//function from the base class in the children if that brings a solution
Base* A::generate(){
    return new A();
}
```

This is all well and good, but I have no way of adding the `generate` function for every component to the map short of `insert`ing every one in main before I do anything else. At which point, I would still be hard-coding for every component and I might as well just use the if-else.

I would be okay with defining the generate function in each header (despite them all being the same and it effectively just abstracting the hard-coding to multiple files as opposed to one) iff I could automatically register the classes into the map.

Is there a way to use the function-pointer map solution? Or moreso, Is there a way to do achieve this behavior in the parser that doesn't involve hard-coding for every component? The rest of the software so far adapts to any new components defined automatically, so it would be really nice to not have to manually add components every time I make a new one.

Comment: Looks like a factory design pattern and you want it to be self registering.

Comment: Technically your cpp files are also text files, so you're already doing it

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you immensely for a serious answer. After doing research this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I was hoping for someone to answer or find a good duplicate that details the self-registration and problem you may have with if you use a static library for the factories.

Comment: I went off of [this](http://derydoca.com/2019/03/c-tutorial-auto-registering-factory/) link which explains factories, how to make them in cpp, and example code for a common usecase. Very useful and I was able to adapt it to my code very easily

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a old question . . .

In the below code, you have a static list of classes that may be generated, via a `std::initalizer_list` and an "add" function, where you can add later even more class creators.

Additionally, I solved the problem with the different signatures in constructors with `std::any`

Maybe this is interesting for other people, facing the same problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the factory with an initializer list
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };

    // Add a new entry for the factory
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```